# Which Ethereum testnet will be supported after the merge (Paris/Bellatrix)?

Tags: testnets, ropsten, goerli, sepolia, the-merge

The Ethereum execution layer (EVM) will be merged with the Ethereum consensus layer (beacon chain) in an event, called *"The Merge."* The code name for the merge will be *Paris* hardfork on the execution layer and *Bellatrix* on the consensus layer before merging their roadmaps.

Which are the testnets that will be officially supported throughout these merge protocol upgrades?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ethereum core developers decided that the following testnets will **be maintained in the future**, including the merge:

- Sepolia Testnet (PoW), chain ID `11155111`, https://sepolia.dev
- Goerli Testnet (PoA), chain ID `5`, https://goerli.net

The following testnets will **no longer receive protocol upgrades** and shall no longer be considered:

- Olympic (PoW, no chain ID, replaced by Morden in 2015)
- Morden (PoW, chain ID `2`, custom starting nonce, replaced by Ropsten in 2016)
- Kovan (PoA, chain ID `42`, retired with Parity Ethereum in 2019)
- Ropsten (PoW, chain ID `3`, replaced by Sepolia in 2021)
- Rinkeby (PoA, chain ID `4`, retired before the merge in 2022)

The Ropsten Testnet (PoW, chain ID `3`) will be receiving the merge upgrade for testing purposes but subsequently be deprecated in 2022.

See also: [OG Council: Post-Merge Testnets](https://ethereum-magicians.org/t/og-council-post-merge-testnets/9034)