# New testnet and what to know after Eth merge and existing test nets deprecation

Tags: rinkeby, cpp-ethereum, the-merge, sepolia

I am just starting to learn solidity in depth and with Eth merge coming, Rinkeby and few other test nets will be depracated.

I tried to get some test Eth with Rinkeby and Sepolia but constantly fail to get test Eth. Which one should I use, any help or links and would there be any difference in coding because a lot of study material uses Rinkeby.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Goerli or Sepolia.  There will not be much difference in coding.

https://ethstaker.cc has a Discord and they can help with testnet ETH.

Source: https://blog.ethereum.org/2022/06/21/testnet-deprecation

Also: [Which Ethereum testnet will be supported after the merge (Paris/Bellatrix)?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/128458/which-ethereum-testnet-will-be-supported-after-the-merge-paris-bellatrix)