# What faucets are available after the merge?

Tags: testnets, faucets

After the merge several test networks were deprecated. [Which Ethereum testnet will be supported after the merge (Paris/Bellatrix)?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/128458/which-ethereum-testnet-will-be-supported-after-the-merge-paris-bellatrix).

Since then goerli has been the favorite and that caused network congestion and faucet being drained.

So what other public test network are available.

Note: There's an similar question [What public test-networks and faucets exist?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84/what-public-test-networks-and-faucets-exist), but since most of the answer point to deprecated networks it seemed better to create a new one.

Comment: The wiki in your second link has been updated. Maybe it should also be posted here and just update here?

Comment: @eth We can mark this as duplicated of the original. I wanted to prevent having many new question looking for a working faucet for goerli.

Comment: If it was my question, I appreciate the comment before closing as duplicate :) But you are able to close this too if that's what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Sepolia Testnet:

- Chain ID: 11155111
- https://faucet.sepolia.dev/
- https://sepoliafaucet.net/
- https://faucet-sepolia.rockx.com/
- https://fauceth.komputing.org/

Mumbai Testnet:

- Chain ID: 80001
- https://mumbaifaucet.com/
- https://faucet.polygon.technology/